# Loadbalancing Liferay Portal Servers Bundled with Jboss using F5

Tags: jboss7.x, load-balancing, liferay-6, f5

We are trying to Load Balance Liferay Portal Servers bundled with Jboss 7.1.1 using F5. When we try reaching the Load Balancer host and port, we are observing a strange behaviour.

If we try to reach https://Loadbalancer_Host:Loadbalancer_Port, we are being redirected to https://Loadbalancer_Host:Liferay_Port/c/portal/layout page.

We have configured the certificates properly on both the Liferay servers and they are accessible individually without any issues.

We are not able to identify whether this is issue with the profile we configured on F5 or are we missing the configuration on Jboss.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, of course make sure that the properties of the source servers that are pointing to the F5 are configured to point to the correct virtual server destination vIP/port/URI (for example https://x.x.x.x:443/c/portal/layout).

What exactly you are trying to do with the virtual server regarding encryption? It appears that either you are trying to do SSL pass-through or a SSL/TLS bridge on the F5, given that you have the certificates on the Liferay servers (appears you are terminating at the Liferay servers). If you are trying to do SSL/TLS pass-through, then you simply do not need a client-side *or* server-side "SSL/TLS" profile for that (just simply configure as you would an http port with no profiles, but keep in mind with this config, you can't do any *layer 7* manipulations such as irules regarding http request/response events, should configure with performance layer 4 or similar, and shouldn't use an http profile obviously. If you are trying to create an "SSL/TLS" bridge, you would use a client-side profile to terminate the SSL/TLS in conjunction with a server-side profile for re-encrypting before sending to the Liferay servers. With an SSL/TLS bridge, you can use layer 7 irules to inspect/manipulate the http traffic.

If you feel like a redirect might be occurring then you can check with an irule to verify that, but again you couldn't set it up unless you are actually trying to create a bridge as mentioned. Use the HTTP Response event declaration, check if the status is a redirect and if so create a log telling you that. The HTTP::is_redirect doesn't work with certain versions, so check for the actual status if you get an error in your LTM logs:

The following response codes cause [HTTP::is_redirect] to return a match (not shown below is that you could also alternatively check the Location header directing the browser to an alternate resource):

-301 (Moved Permanently)
-302 (Found)
-303 (See Other)
-305 (Use Proxy)
-307 (Temporary Redirect)

```
when HTTP_RESPONSE {  

# Check if the status indicates a redirect, use [HTTP::is_redirect] if possible
# if {([HTTP::status] == 302) or ([HTTP::status] == 301) or....}{
if {[HTTP::is_redirect]} {  

   log local0. "There was indeed a redirect"
}  
}
```

If there is a redirect, it would likely be from the ESB, unless you have logic on the F5 that checks for the certain URI and if detected, routes to the other URI. So just make sure someone didn't configure and apply an irule to redirect (which actually can be done at layer 4 for http or https) with something like the following:

```
when CLIENT_ACCEPTED {

#if all of the members in the pool have been marked down by the health monitor
if { [active_members [LB::server pool_name]] <1 } {
TCP::respond "HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nServer: Apache\r\nConnection:     Close\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nLocation: https://www.somewhere.else.com\r\n"
}
}
```

I think that after reading this, you should be able to discern whatever the issue might be if not already resolved, if still not sure happy to try to help.